# Required attribute in ASP Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how to use required attribute in *asp.net*. .In html I used required attribute for mandatory fields. *How to use it in asp .net?*

I tried this so far, is it correct?

```
<p class="field-wrapper required-field">
   <label>First Name</label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="f_name" runat="server" required>
   </asp:TextBox>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's no required attribute. you have to use a RequiredFieldValidator

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" name="f_name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="TextBox1" errormessage="Please enter a value!" />
```

Comment: Is it available in standard tool?

Comment: yes asp:RequiredFieldValidator should be available - you don't need a additional framework